# DOM manipulation, dynamic filtering (vanilla js). I can log them in the console, but when I display them in HTML, products aren't filtered(all shown)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

sorry for my ugly snippet but I think it's decent for showing you what's going on with my code. It's been 3 days non stop that I am trying new things to fix it and I really can't. Using plain vanilla js, is it possible to give me a hint on how to display only the products that match the product id? for example if it's 1, only show milk. if it's 2 only show cocoa milk. If it's 3 only show almond milk. I am unable to do the filtering. I also tried to change the html variable in the foreach loop.. The reason that I am not asking for jquery for example is because I am doing this exercise to learn. So jquery can solve the problem but i havent learnt it yet.

**I get the items correctly in the console. So for example if i console.log category 1 then the items are displayed properly there. But when it comes with html, every item is alywas shown no matter what....Can someone please help? I am completely lost.**

```js
const product1 = {
  p_image: "https://3z6mv8219w2s2w196j1dkzga-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/turtletree-labs.jpg",
  p_title: "Milk",
  p_price: 145,
  id: 1,
};
const product2 = {
  p_image: "https://chriskresser.com/wp-content/uploads/raw-milk-1-e1563894986431.jpg",
  p_title: "Milk2",
  p_price: 512,
  id: 1,
};
const product3 = {
  p_image: "https://i2.wp.com/www.eatthis.com/wp-content/uploads/media/images/ext/621263600/chocolate-milk-straw.jpg?fit=1024%2C750&ssl=1",
  p_title: "Cocoa milk",
  p_price: 111,
  id: 2,
};
const product4 = {
  p_image: "https://silk.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/silk-original-almondmilk-4.png",
  p_title: "Almond milk",
  p_price: 133,
  id: 3,
};




const products = [
  product1,
  product2,
  product3,
  product4
]



const containerProducts = document.querySelector(".product-center-container");
const displayProducts = function() {
  containerProducts.innerHTML = "";

  products.forEach((element) => {
    const html = `
      <div class="product-center-container">
      <div class="product" id=${element.id}>
      <a href="pDescription.html"><img class ="p_image" src="${element.p_image}"></a>
      <h1 class="p_title">${element.p_title}</h1>
      <h4 class="p_price">${element.p_price}.-</h4>
      <button class="itemsToCart"><img src="images/cartAdd.png" alt="Basket displayed here"></button>
      </div>
      </div>
      `;


    containerProducts.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
  });
};
// displayProducts();




const filterProducts = function(productId) {
      products.forEach(product => {
        if (product.id === productId ){
              displayProducts();
              console.log(product);
        } 
      });
}
filterProducts(3);



// const filterProducts = function(productId) {
// let newArr = [];
//  products.forEach(product => {
//    if (product.id === productId) {
//      newArr.push(product);
//   /  }
//   });
//   displayProducts(newArr);
//  console.log(newArr);
// }
// filterProducts(3);
```

```css
.p_image{width: 150px;)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="product-center-container">
        <div class="product">
            <a href="pDescription.html"><img class="p_image" src=""></a>
            <h1 class="p_title">Title</h1>
            <h4 class="p_price">Price</h4>
            <button class="itemsToCart"><img src="images/cartAdd.png" alt="Basket displayed here"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start the expalantion. So the first thing is you need to filter out the products properly and the forEach does not work like that.

You need to use `find`.

I will not provide you a full example, just for the learning purposes. Heres the pseudo code:

```
const filteredProduct = products.find(x => x.id === specificId)
```

The code above will return you a specifc object that matches the specific ID.

Now you can use that object anywhere you would like. You can make a function that returns the object with a specifc ID and invoke the function inside your code.

And you dont need to do `products.forEach` to display a single filtered object. Remember, that `find` will return an object for you, because you store objects inside your array.

This allows you to call `displayProduct(filteredProduct)`

You have mentioned that you want to display products that match `id`. Well `id` is a unique identifier you dont want to have elements with the same `id`, so `find` will return only a single element.

If you want to return multiple elements, that matches the specific criteria, you can use higher order function `filter`.

```
const filteredProducts = products.filter(x => x.name === name)
```

This returns an array that matches the given condition, which is name.

Now we can call a function `displayProducts(filteredProducts)`.

Now you have to iterate over filtered products and display them!

```
const displayProducts = (filteredProducts) => { filteredProducts.map(x => { return //return html element here
```

We prefer to use `map` for example if you want to return some sort of new array or some sort of html elements, we do not use `forEach` for that.

I know that solving issue and writing the exact code for you would help you a lot more, but you wont find it usefull for urself.

Hope this helps! If you need any help, let me know in the comments.

PS. I would offer you to start using a JS framework if its possible, it will make your life way easier. Once you dig onto the JS framework, youll focus more on learning Javascript, because framework makes everything easier.